# Create a run script to package and zip compiled library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, bash

So I want to create a run script (build phase) that will automatically create a .zip folder with the compiled library (.a file) and all the relevant .h files that are needed for distribution.

Does anyone have a sample bash script for this? Something that can be replicated reliably over different projects?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't includ the distribution build check.

```
echo "Tar $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/ to ~/Desktop/myHeader.tar"
tar -cvf ~/Desktop/myHeader.tar -C $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/ .
echo "DONE with script:"
```

Note: it only include the public header + the static lib. I haven't tried how that could work if you include more than one static lib. Hope this can give you some clues, worked for me

Comment: Don't forget that you need to to a fat library or include all your static in order to compile in all architecture version. I've just give you what you wanted

Comment: Can you expand on that at all please?

Comment: If you create a libxxx.a for i386 architecture (simulator), that will not work on real device (armv6, armv7, arvm7s). You need to include one for each architecture, or make a fat file which include all

Comment: Ah, you just made me 100% more confused! :p lol - thanks! haha I'll look into that.